# How to get result to array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I’m new to angular and I just started dealing with mongodb using mongoose.

In my application I need to get name list of drivers as string array, but, I’m getting array of objects with object id.

```
{
            "_id": "5aa90ab23c49a72488afab7a",
            "name": "mr. Rusiru ekanayaka"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5aa90d4ba8c6b35438a8b132",
            "name": "mr. Gihan ekanayaka"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5aa90d56a8c6b35438a8b133",
            "name": "mr. Gihan ekanayaka"
        }
}
```

But I need something like this,

```
[
  ' mr. Gihan ekanayaka,
  ' mr. rusiru ekanayaka ',
  ' mr. Gihan ekanayaka '
]
```

I think I can re-format this in my backend by looping through the object. By is there anyway to get only one field of document in collection as string array without object id?

In my Driver model I do like this.

```
module.exports.getDrivers = function(callback){
  Driver.find({},'name',callback);
}
```

Comment: try `module.exports.getDrivers = function(callback){
  Driver.distinct('name',callback);
}`

Comment: @Veeram this returns only distinct values. What happens when there are two drivers with same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
module.exports.getDrivers = function(callback){
  Driver.find({},{'_id' : 0,'name' : 1},callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module.exports.getDrivers = function(callback){

Driver.distinct('name', callback);

}
```

Comment: this returns only distinct values. What happens when there are two drivers with same name?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), for example like this:

```
Driver.find({}).map(driver => driver.name);
```

That (with adjustments to the code to fit your coding environment) will return an array of driver.name items, like this:

```
[
  "mr. Rusiru ekanayaka",
  "mr. Gihan ekanayaka",
  "mr. Gihan ekanayaka"
]
```

Comment: when i do like this it gives this error ->  Vehicle.find(...).map is not a function.....